# Exception when trying to create MySQL connection with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have been getting an exception while creating first ever application in hibernate. I did search but the solutions provided didn't help me. What odd I am doing here due to which I have burned my hours on this.

Please see the content below to better point out the issue.[image: Project Structure with all libraries being used]

Student.java

```
package beans;

public class Student {
    private int studentId;
    private String name;
    private int marks;
    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }
    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }


}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2dll.auto">create</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="resources/Student.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Student.hbm.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="beans.Student" table="student" schema="school">
        <id name="studentId"/>
        <property name="name"/>
        <property name="marks"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Test.java

```
package test;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.addResource("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

Yes, I have double checked that there is a username and password both root and I have also created db named school and port is 3306.

Exception:

```
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The application must supply JDBC connections
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:723)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:8)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Could you perhaps share the exception with us?

Comment: I have just shared the exception. Please suggest. Thanks @PerHuss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call `configure` method

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration().configure();
```

add this it will work.

also from hibernate 4, you can initialize with `ServiceRegistry`, have a look at the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Tricky one! The culprit seems to be how you configure your session factory. The `addResource()` is for loading mappings, but silently ignores all the other settings. Try this instead:

```
conf.configure(new File("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml"))
    .buildSessionFactory();
```

Good luck with your project!